# Changing 'href' using JS/jQuery not working on the first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Having this simple HTML:

```
<a id="show-modal-button" class="circle modal" href='#' >
    <i class="fa fa-plus circle-inner-icon"></i>
</a>
```

And this script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   window.addEvent('domready', function()
   {
        $('show-modal-button').onclick = function(ev) {             
            ev.preventDefault();
            modalUrl = 'http://www.google.es'
            $('show-modal-button').href = modalUrl;
            console.log($('show-modal-button').href);
            return false;
         });
   });
</script>
```

It doesnt work on the first click. The modal opens on the first click but nothing is shown (blank modal). If I close the modal and click on the buttom again, the modal shows the href page (in the example above, google) correctly.

I've read some other threads with the same problem and people solve it adding `return false;` but I add that line and still doesnt work.

The `console.log` prints the correct url on the first click.. I also tested with `$('show-modal-button').addEvent('click', function (ev) {` with no luck :(

Any ideas how to make this work on the first attemp?

Comment: weird code `$('show-modal-button').onclick`? mix of jQuery and native JS

Comment: You're missing `}` after your `onclick` handler function

Comment: If you are using jQuery for your application, use all the features provided by jQuery. Don't mix with jQuery and JavaScript. Use $(document).ready(function (){}); instead using window.addEvent('domready...

Comment: as commented above, use pure jQuery for your dom ready. see my ans below, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other comments :

- *[Selecting elements with their id](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) in jquery is done by prepending "#" to the id*
- *Changing an element's attribute in jquery is done by using the function [attr(name, value)](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)*
- *Inside your click function, you can refer to your jquery element by using [$(this)](https://api.jquery.com/click/)*

See this working snippet :

```js
$(function(){
 $("#show-modal-button").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
    var modalUrl = 'http://www.google.es';
    $(this).attr('href', modalUrl);
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="show-modal-button" class="circle modal" href='#' >
    <i class="fa fa-plus circle-inner-icon">show modal</i>
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this..

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

  $(function(){
$('show-modal-button').click(function(ev) {             
            ev.preventDefault();
            modalUrl = 'http://www.google.es'
            $('show-modal-button').href = modalUrl;
            console.log($('show-modal-button').href);
            return false;
});
});

</script>
```